# Malicious JavaScript warning

Tags: malware, javascript

I visited a site yesterday and received no malicious javascript warnngs.  Today I visited that same site and got the warnings.  *Do I need to be worried about being infected with something?*

Answer (score 4):

Go to https://www.virustotal.com/

Put in the URL of the website you visited that gave you the JavaScript warning.

It will search to see if that URL has malicious content.

You will get results.

Unless there is zero-day malware on that URL, the results will be correct.